# Report Viewer Cell Empty

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer

I got a Report Viewer report in Visual Studio.Net 2008. I added a new field to the dataset (get value from a stored procedure) and also added to the report as an expression:

=First(Fields!SalesType.Value)

But when I run the report the value above is blank for every single row in the report.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that there is a connection string that some ass hard coded in a class so its pointing to production and not development where I confusingly made the changes.